# S3 object creation trigger event to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have created an AWS lambda trigger from S3 - create object notification. When lambda gets object creation notification it also launches the ec2 instance. For the next step, I want ec2 to access the object/data form s3 and do some processing on that data. How can I access that data from ec2?

Answer (score 2):

When the Lambda function launches the EC2 instance, I would have it pass the S3 object key as part of the [EC2 user-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-add-user-data.html).

Comment: thank you for your response. But the point is the user-data script will run only when ec2 lunches. I need to copy every data uploaded to the s3 bucket.
Are there any way of doing that?

Comment: Your question indicated you are launching a new EC2 instance each time an new object is uploaded to S3. Is that not the case?

Comment: If the instance is already up and running I don't want to lunch a new one. I just want already run EC2  to continue processing with newly uploaded objects.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should just have S3 push notifications to SQS, and have a pool of auto-scaled EC2 instance that read from SQS. You don't need AWS Lambda at all for that.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are wanting to use an existing Amazon EC2 instance to process objects that are uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket.

The standard method for doing this is:

- Create an **Amazon SQS queue**
- Configure the **Amazon S3 bucket** to send a message to the SQS queue when a new object is created
- Write code on the **Amazon EC2 instance** that continuously polls the Amazon SQS queue, asking for a message (use `WaitTimeSeconds=20` to reduce the number of calls, it will return immediately if a message is available)
- Once a **message is received**, the code can download the S3 object (the Bucket and Key are provided in the message) and then process the file. Once the file is processed, your code should **delete the SQS message**

If there are long time-periods between object uploads and you wish to save money, you could add some logic to your code that does a **Shutdown of the instance** when no messages have been received for a given period of time. You could then create an **Amazon CloudWatch alarm** based on queue size that can trigger an AWS Lambda function to Start the instance if it is not currently Running.

To run a script every time that an Amazon EC2 instance starts, you can place it in `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/`.

See also: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: Big Thanks John it works for our case